# Puppet run order

Tags: puppet

I've got a question on how to best do this senario, I've got a number of exec commands which need to be run in this order

```
Exec['A'] -> Exec['B']-> if var = 1(Exec['x']) if var = 2(Exec['y']) if var = 3 (Exec['z]) -> Exec['C'] -> Exec['D']
```

Basically I have an Exec then I have if statements and then I need to call an exec.

At this moment I've done the following

```
Exec['A'] { before Exec['B'] } 
Exec['B'] { subscribe Exec['A'] }
if var = 1(Exec['x']) { before Exec['C'] }
if var = 2(Exec['y']) { before Exec['C'] }
if var = 3 (Exec['z]) { before Exec['C'] }
Exec['C'] { before Exec['D'] }
Exec['D']
```

I'm not sure if this code is idempotent, I just want to confirm with the community in case they see anything I may not be seeing. I have a feeling that the if statements could run before the Exec['A'] which I do not want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is off, but this does indeed work

```
Exec['A'] { before => Exec['B'] }
if $var == 1 {
  Exec['x'] { before => Exec['C'] }
}
else {
  Exec['y'] { before => Exec['C'] }
}
```

Note that this code assumes that all the `exec` resources A, B, C, x and y have already been declared without any respective `before` parameters.

Answer (score 0):

If you want x,y, and z to run after A, then add `require => Exec['A']`.

Also, it appears all of the execs will run with every puppet run. Add a `onlyif`, `unless`, `creates`, or `refreshonly` attribute.

Comment: Is "after" even a flag that is usable in puppet? Last I checked it was before or require and notify and subscribe.

Answer (score 0):

To automatically test idempotence of your script, you may be interested in this tool: https://github.com/citac/citac

Citac systematically executes your Puppet manifest in various configurations, different resource execution orders, and more. The generated test reports inform you about issues with non-idempotent resources, convergence-related issues, etc.

The tool uses Docker containers for execution, hence your system remains untouched while testing. State changes are tracked during execution of the Puppet script, and detailed test reports are generated.

Please feel free to provide feedback, pull requests, etc. Happy testing!